# Is it possible to write two condition in one curly braces?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have to render two component base on the two different condition first one component should display if `isAllowed` flag is true. and another component must be display if `isAllowed` and `isEditMode` is true. and I more conditions in same render method which depend on `isAllowed` flag.

currently i achieved this by implementing below code.

```
render(){
 return (
   <div>
    {
       isAllowed && <span> component 1 </span>
    }
    {
       isAllowed && isEditMode && <span> component 2 </span>
    }
    {
       isAllowed && 3 more condition && <span> component 3 </span>
    }
   {
       isAllowed && 4 more condition && <span> component 4 </span>
    }
   </div>
 )
}
```

I want to do common check of `isAllowed`. because its common in both the cases. is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a React `Fragment` to check `isActive` once, and check `isEditMode` inside of that.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { isAllowed, isEditMode } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        {isAllowed && (
          <React.Fragment>
            <span> component 1 </span>
            {isEditMode && <span> component 2 </span>}
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App isAllowed isEditMode />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an array:

```
render() {
  const components = [];
  if (isAllowed) {
    components.push(<span> component 1 </span>);
    if (isEditMode) {
      components.push(<span> component 2 </span>);
    }
  }
  return <div>{ components }</div>;
}
```

This provides greater flexibility, especially if you have many components and different conditions. Of course you can also do it in an inline expression, not separate statements, if you can keep it readable:

```
return <div>{
  isAllowed
    ? [
      <span> component 1 </span>,
      isEditMode ? <span> component 2 </span> : null
    ]
    : null
}</div>
```

or

```
return <div>{
  isAllowed && [
    <span> component 1 </span>,
    isEditMode && <span> component 2 </span>
  ]
}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. you can use ternary operation for this

```
{isAllowed && <Fragment>{isEditMode ? 'When editing' : 'When not editing'}</Fragment>}
```

Comment: What if i have third condition ?

Comment: Then you will need to wrap all your condition with an isAllowed condition and inside to have multiple if's or a switch.

Comment: is it possible inside curly braces without using if.

Comment: `{condition&&<span/>}` - This is an equivailent of an If statement in JSX

Comment: for just two conditions your answer is suitable. +1